# What does orange light on power supply mean?

Tags: intel, power-supply-unit

I have an Intel® Server System P4000CP Family. Today I've discovered that one of power supply has green light, second power supply has orange light. What does it mean?

Comment: Hello. Could You, provide a bit more info? Like what power supply is used there?

Comment: @Ollie, Hello. I don't know. How can I find out it? Server in the production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000007372/server-products/server-chassis.html

> The system Power Supply is in a **degraded** or in a failed state if any
> of the following is encountered:
>
> - Front Panel Status LED is blinking green.
> - Information regarding a failed or degraded Power Supply is written in the System Event Logs.
> - In the Active System Console, under Power Supply, the status indicates Failed.
> - The redundant **PSU LED is amber** (if checked physically at the
>   back of the chassis).

Intel calls this color "amber".  Not orange.

---

I should add that in my case, the amber LED only meant "there is no power in the cable".